# Fastest way to check for a value across rows in the same group?

Tags: r

I'm struggling with the way to check whether the value of a variable for each case is the same as the value of a different variable, within groups, and without usign for() loops. I'd be thankful if anyone could help me. These are a simplified form of my data:

```
library(data.table)

df<-data.table(personid<-c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 201, 202, 203, 301, 302, 401),
       hh_id<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
       fatherid<-c(NA, NA, 101, 101, 101, NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA),
```

(the real one is 185000 rows and fatherid is not the only variable that I need to cjeck)

What I'm trying to do is to create a variable that checks whether the value of variable `personid` of a given row is the same as the value of `fatherid` within the members of the same group (the grouping variable is hh_id). For the given data, the outcome should be:

```
df$result <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

but I need something to do it automatically. Any ideas?

In case you want to understand the sense of my calculations, I'm trying to build household grids; this is: whether each observation is the father of at least another observation within the same household (hh_id)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your first `fatherid` is NA. How can the result be `1`?

Comment: You can use `df[,by=hh_id, result:= personid==fatherid]`.

Comment: @MartinGal, the result is 1 in the first row as person 101 is the father of some other household members (103,104, and 105). I've tried your solution, but then I get an error: "Error in `[.data.table`(df, , by = hh_id, `:=`(result, personid == fatherid)) : 
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 5 in column 'result'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.". Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Does your example data represent your _actual_ data? Does the error occure with the example? If not, please update your example.

Comment: Yes, it does. Okay, this is weird. I don't know why but now it worked perfectly as I wanted... Thank you very much for your help! I'm not familiar with data.table syntax. (I normally use data.frame or dplyr) do you know where I could learn more about the meaning of the different punctuation signs that appear in your syntax? Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw once a `data.table` tutorial online, but don't know the link. Most likely there are some fine sources online. I usally use `dplyr`, so I'm not very familiar with `data.table`. Please consider accepting the answer below, if it solves your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* you are looking for this:

```
df[, result2 := personid %in% fatherid, by = hh_id]

#     personid hh_id fatherid result result2
#  1:      101     1       NA      1    TRUE
#  2:      102     1       NA      0   FALSE
#  3:      103     1      101      0   FALSE
#  4:      104     1      101      0   FALSE
#  5:      105     1      101      0   FALSE
#  6:      201     2       NA      1    TRUE
#  7:      202     2       NA      0   FALSE
#  8:      203     2      201      0   FALSE
#  9:      301     3       NA      0   FALSE
# 10:      302     3       NA      0   FALSE
# 11:      401     4       NA      0   FALSE
```

Where

```
df <- data.table(
  personid = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 201, 202, 203, 301, 302, 401),
  hh_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
  fatherid = c(NA, NA, 101, 101, 101, NA, NA, 201, NA, NA, NA),
  result = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but then I get an error: "Error in [.data.table(df, , by = hh_id, :=(result, personid == fatherid)) : Supplied 11 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 5 in column 'result'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.". Any ideas why this is not working?